# Sympy coeff not consistent with as_independent

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following snippet of code

```
import sympy

a = sympy.symbols('a')
b = sympy.symbols('b')
c = sympy.symbols('c')

print((a*b).coeff(c,0))
print((a*b).as_independent(c)[0])
```

I don't understand why the two print statements print different output. According to the documentation of coeff:

```
You can select terms independent of x by making n=0; in this case
expr.as_independent(x)[0] is returned (and 0 will be returned instead
of None):

>>> (3 + 2*x + 4*x**2).coeff(x, 0)
3
```

Is this a bug in sympy, or do I miss something?

Comment: This looks like a bug. Can you [open an issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/new)?

Comment: I've made a fix for this [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/11590).

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug. I have a pull request fixing it [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/11590).